# Flask: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, utf-8

I am working on a python project using the flask module. It's not the first time i've used it but i am still very much a novice. While i was setting up a very simple file this error came up: *UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte*
This is my app.py file:

```
from flask import Flask,render_template

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates')

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", debug=True)
```

and this is my index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Flask app</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello world</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem only occurs when i try to render the template as if i take out the render template and substitute it with somthing like `return "Hello world"`i don't have any problems and by going to the site i see Hello world.

What is the cause of the error? Python's version is 3.10 and i am on a linux pc

I've tried to redo this code on my windows pc with python 3.9.13 i have no problem, while by using my linux computer with python 3.10 i keep encountering it.

Comment: Please search for the error message online. Also, check the encoding of the files you're working with.

Comment: An `0xFF in position 0` often means the file being read is UTF-16-encoded and the 0xFF is the first byte of a `FF FE` little-endian UTF-16 byte order mark (BOM).  Double-check that your file is saved in UTF-8 as declared.

Comment: @MarkTolonen indeed the file was encoded in utf-16 and not in utf-8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it might be happening because of the encoding you use while editing the HTML. Try to run this code and run the app.py afterwards:

```
f1 = open("templates/index.html","r").read()
open("templates/index.html","wb").write(f1.encode("utf-8"))
```

I hope it works!

Comment: i tried running this but it gave me another unicode error when trying to open the file but as said by @marktolonen on the comment under my initial question the file was encoded in utf-16. I just specified the encoding variable in the code as such `f1 = open("templates/index.html","r", encoding="utf-16").read()` and the problem seems to be resolved.